# How to check if the particular value is present in a dataframe (First row) using Java?

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to check if the Dataframe which i have evaluated has the value '1' in the first row.

Below is the dataframe I have developed in Java

```
Dataset<Row> set = spark.sql(sample); 
set.show();

+--------------------+
||A|B|C|D|E|
+--------------------+
||0|1|0|0|0|
||2|3|5|3|5|
----------+----------+
```

I tried using the first() and head() but couldn't arrive at the solution.

Only requirement is I need to read the 1st row of the above dataframe and check if the value '1' is present or not.. if yes print "present" else "not present". Could anyone suggest solution using Java. TIA

Answer (score 0):

`set.take(1)` will return the first row only

Then run `select("B")` or `where("B == 1")` and compare the content/size of the dataframe to get "present"